# Google App Engine - Static files getting downloaded

Tags: google-app-engine

I've got a GAE application with a directory called *static* with two sub-directories *css* and *js.* Each of these directories have CSS and JavaScript files respectively. In my HTML code I've got references to these files such as:

```
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
```

And my app.yaml file looks like this:

```
application: ********
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico 
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

However, the CSS styles and JavaScript files aren't applied to the HTML code and when I view source and click on the links in the code, the CSS and JS files open up in a new tab and a download prompt pops up.

**Q:** Why are these files being downloaded instead of being linked with my HTML?

**EDIT:** I'm not sure if this is relevant but my GAE logs reveal that the request is returned with a 304 response:

```
INFO     2015-02-05 18:43:51,229 module.py:639] default: "GET /static/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

**EDIT 2:** Looking at my Google Chrome developer tools' network tab I came to know that the mime type for these files is *application/x-js* and *application/x-css.* Now, I'm certain that this is the cause of my problems but why is the mime type so when the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles) clearly mention that,

> By default, App Engine serves static files using a MIME type based on the filename extension. For example, a file with a name ending in .css will be served with a MIME type of text/css.

I tried modifying the mime type through app.yaml by explicitly specifying the mime types but it still doesn't change.

Comment: Is this happening on your local or out on GAE?  The files in the static directory get cached and may not see any mime type changes you are making.

Comment: It's happening on my local machine but I don't think it's a caching issue since this has been happening since the first time I requested the files. @JeffDeskins

Comment: Status `304` means `not modified`, so the `GET` is a conditional one (meaning the client claims to have some version cached) and the server's not bothering to send another copy, as the cached one is still good.  More troublesome is to see `GET /js/`&c when you claim you're using `src="/static/js/`&c (**very** different URL!) *and* you're serving under the latter URL, **not** the one showing up in your logs, per `- url: /static` in your `app.yaml`.  Overall, this picture's impossible -- there must be some inconsistency in what you're showing us!

Comment: @AlexMartelli I'm sorry I just copied the wrong log line. But I'm absolutely sure that the server is actually sending the file to the browser as is indicated by the browser network inspector. The only problem is with the mime type.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I resolved to clean the staging bucket.

For do this, I open bucket section on my GCP console and you remove all file in the bucket with name staging.{projectname}.appspot.com